# How to sort data to a more friendly timeseries data after applying reshape melt()

Tags: r, sorting, melt

I have the following data  after melting using reshape2::melt()

```
          CustomerName variable value
1        Aaron Bergman  01-2009     0
2        Aaron Hawkins  01-2009     0
3       Aaron Smayling  01-2009   136
4      Adam Bellavance  01-2009     0
5            Adam Hart  01-2009    61
6   Adam Shillingsburg  01-2009     0
7        Adrian Barton  01-2009     0
8          Adrian Hane  01-2009     0
9         Adrian Shami  01-2009     0
10         Aimee Bixby  01-2009     0
11       Aaron Bergman  02-2009     0
12       Aaron Hawkins  02-2009     0
13      Aaron Smayling  02-2009  4659
14     Adam Bellavance  02-2009     0
15           Adam Hart  02-2009     0
16  Adam Shillingsburg  02-2009  1750
17       Adrian Barton  02-2009     0
18         Adrian Hane  02-2009     0
19        Adrian Shami  02-2009     0
20         Aimee Bixby  02-2009     0
21       Aaron Bergman  03-2009     0
22       Aaron Hawkins  03-2009     0
23      Aaron Smayling  03-2009     0
24     Adam Bellavance  03-2009     0
25           Adam Hart  03-2009     0
26  Adam Shillingsburg  03-2009   126
27       Adrian Barton  03-2009     0
28         Adrian Hane  03-2009     0
29        Adrian Shami  03-2009     0
30         Aimee Bixby  03-2009     0
31       Aaron Bergman  04-2009     0
32       Aaron Hawkins  04-2009     0
33      Aaron Smayling  04-2009   119
34     Adam Bellavance  04-2009     0
35           Adam Hart  04-2009     0
36  Adam Shillingsburg  04-2009     0
37       Adrian Barton  04-2009     0
38         Adrian Hane  04-2009     0
39        Adrian Shami  04-2009     0
40         Aimee Bixby  04-2009     0
41       Aaron Bergman  05-2009     0
42       Aaron Hawkins  05-2009     0
43      Aaron Smayling  05-2009  4674
44     Adam Bellavance  05-2009  2108
45           Adam Hart  05-2009     0
46  Adam Shillingsburg  05-2009     0
47       Adrian Barton  05-2009     0
48         Adrian Hane  05-2009     0
49        Adrian Shami  05-2009     0
50         Aimee Bixby  05-2009     0
```

I would like to have same customers rows together rather than assorted as above.Also the month should be sorted in increasing order....Would like any pointers as to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in base R you could use:

```
yourOrderedDataFrame<-
  yourDataFrame[order(yourDataFrame$CustomerName,yourDataFrame$variable),]
```